# Regex to add hyphens at specific location of string

Tags: php, regex

I found this regex which works fine if there are no alphabets in provided string.

```
$string = "12522191813381147500333332228323";
echo $formattedString = preg_replace("/^(\d{8})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{12})$/", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5", $string);
```

My input string would be sometime mix of alphabets and numbers. What changes I have to do to make it work in both the cases. I have other alternative to iterate a string and add dashes using string functions of PHP but I want to learn how we can achieve it using regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` also allows underscores, if you really only want to allow alphanumeric characters, you'd have to do something like this:

```
([a-z0-9]{8})([a-z0-9]{4})
```

And include a `i` flag at the end of the regex (after the final `/`) to make it case insensitive.

Comment: +1 and thanks for case insensitive part. Completely missed that!